# Installing sqldeveloper – dependency problems: sqldeveloper depends on libc6-amd64 (>= 2.2.5)

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, glibc, alien, sqldeveloper

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sqldeveloper: sqldeveloper depends on libc6-amd64 (>= 2.2.5).

dpkg: error processing package sqldeveloper (--install):dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing: sqldeveloper
```

`sudo apt-cache policy libc6-amd64`

```
libc6-amd64:i386:
  Installed: 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
  Candidate: 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
  Version table:
 *** 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux Inspiron-3537 3.19.0-28-generic #30~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 1 09:32:55 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`sudo apt-get remove -s libc6-amd64:i386`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  lib64gcc1:i386 lib64stdc++6:i386 libc6-amd64:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Remv lib64stdc++6:i386 [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04]
Remv lib64gcc1:i386 [1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1]
Remv libc6-amd64:i386 [2.19-0ubuntu6.6]
```

`sudo apt-get remove libc6-amd64:i386`
`sudo dpkg -i sqldeveloper_4.1.1.19.59-2_all.deb`

```
/WorkSpace/DataBase$ sudo dpkg --install sqldeveloper_4.1.1.19.59-2_all.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package sqldeveloper.
(Reading database ... 260675 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack sqldeveloper_4.1.1.19.59-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking sqldeveloper (4.1.1.19.59-2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sqldeveloper:
 sqldeveloper depends on libc6-amd64 (>= 2.2.5).

dpkg: error processing package sqldeveloper (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sqldeveloper
```

`sudo apt-cache policy libc6`

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
  Candidate: 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
  Version table:
 *** 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

`cat DEBIAN/control`

```
Package: sqldeveloper
Version: 4.1.1.19.59-2
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Ankit Chaudhary <anki@Inspiron-3537>
Installed-Size: 393765
Depends: libc6-amd64 (>= 2.2.5), libc6-i386 (>= 2.1.3)
Section: alien
Priority: extra
Description: Oracle SQL Developer
 Oracle SQL Developer is a new, free graphical tool that enhances productivity and simplifies database development tasks. With SQL Developer, you can browse database objects, run SQL statements and SQL scripts, and edit and debug PL/SQL statements. You can also run any number of provided reports, as well as create and save your own.
 .
 (Converted from a rpm package by alien version 8.90.)
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libc6-amd64`

Comment: @A.B. i add  the output of apt-cache policy libc6-amd64

Comment: i found deb file from the link    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

Comment: sorry i download rpm file and then convert it into deb file through alien

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `uname -a`

Comment: i dont understand you sir

Comment: Open a terminal and start the command `uname -a` Take the output and paste in your question.

Comment: Linux Inspiron-3537 3.19.0-28-generic #30~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 1 09:32:55 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: What is the full name of your deb file, created via alien?

Comment: sqldeveloper-4.1.1.19.59-1.noarch.rpm

Comment: and the name of the deb file?

Comment: Please start the command `sudo apt-get remove -s libc6-amd64:i386` and add the output into your question via [edit]. The command removes nothing `-s` means simulate.

Comment: sqldeveloper_4.1.1.19.59-2_all.deb

Comment: Ok, remove the package `libc6-amd64:i386` via `sudo apt-get remove libc6-amd64:i386` AFTER that, install `sqldeveloper_4.1.1.19.59-2_all.deb` again via `sudo dpkg -i sqldeveloper_4.1.1.19.59-2_all.deb` and give me the output by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: sudo dpkg --install sqldeveloper_4.1.1.19.59-2_all.deb               sir by this or by your command

Comment: It's the same. and don't say "Sir" please =)

Comment: i post the output

Comment: I see, repair the installation again.

Comment: sudo apt-get purge sqldeveloper
sudo apt-get install -f                                     by this code or simply by sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge sqldeveloper; sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Done.                       Removing sqldeveloper (4.1.1.19.59-2) ...
Purging configuration files for sqldeveloper (4.1.1.19.59-2) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing sqldeveloper, directory '/usr/local' not empty so not removed
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy libc6`

Comment: check the output in question

Comment: Ok, now get some commands. Start please conscientiously.

Comment: Go into the folder, where the `sqldeveloper_4.1.1.19.59-2_all.deb` is.

Comment: Start `mkdir deb$$; cp sqldeveloper_4.1.1.19.59-2_all.deb deb$$; cd deb$$; dpkg-deb -x sqldeveloper_4.1.1.19.59-2_all.deb deb; cd deb; dpkg-deb -e ../sqldeveloper_4.1.1.19.59-2_all.deb; cat DEBIAN/control` and add the output into your question

Comment: when i click on deb file then ubuntu software centre open automatically and i found an error : "dependency is not satisfiable: libc6-amd64(=2.2.5)"

Comment: Start the command above =)

Comment: i perform all above commands. check output in question

Comment: And the output is?

Comment: check output in question

Comment: Done, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have used `alien`, e.g.

```
sudo alien --script sqldeveloper-4.1.1.19.59-1.noarch.rpm
```

to create a deb package. Unfortunately, the created package can not be installed in your system because the package `libc6-amd64` isn't available for Trusty in the needed version.

Repair your installation via

```
sudo apt-get purge sqldeveloper
sudo apt-get install -f
```

---

The interesting thing though is, in my case, that the generated DEB package has no dependence on `libc6-amd64`. But in your case... ok

Therefore start the command below. Copy and paste the whole block into a terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
mkdir deb$$; \
cp sqldeveloper_4.1.1.19.59-2_all.deb deb$$; \
cd deb$$; dpkg-deb -x sqldeveloper_4.1.1.19.59-2_all.deb deb; \
cd deb; \
dpkg-deb -e ../sqldeveloper_4.1.1.19.59-2_all.deb
```

Now start

```
cat DEBIAN/control
```

and you should see something like this

```
Package: sqldeveloper
Version: 4.1.1.19.59-2
Architecture: all
Maintainer: root <root@sturm>
Installed-Size: 393753
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5), libc6-i386 (>= 2.1.3)
Section: alien
Priority: extra
Description: Oracle SQL Developer
 Oracle SQL Developer is a new, free graphical tool that enhances productivity and simplifies database development tasks. With SQL Developer, you can browse database objects, run SQL statements and SQL scripts, and edit and debug P$
 .
 (Converted from a rpm package by alien version 8.93.)
```

but not in your case. **o_O**

Therefore start the commands below to correct this and re-build the package

```
sed -i 's/libc6-amd64/libc6/' DEBIAN/control
cd ..
sudo dpkg-deb -b deb
```

Finally install with

```
sudo dpkg -i deb.deb
```

and that's all **;)**

---

Make the first start please from the terminal, in my case had to be answered there a question.

```
sqldeveloper
```

You will see

```
 Oracle SQL Developer
 Copyright (c) 1997, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Type the full pathname of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in /home/aboettger/.sqldeveloper/4.1.0/product.conf
```

And I have used

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Comment: i tried this method also but its not working

Comment: Which method? Repair your installation.

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: Ok. Purge the package first.

Comment: sir i got this.                Removing sqldeveloper (4.1.1.19.59-2) ...
Purging configuration files for sqldeveloper (4.1.1.19.59-2) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing sqldeveloper, directory '/usr/local' not empty so not removed

Comment: `warning: while removing sqldeveloper, directory '/usr/local'` is ok. Bad if it were not that way. Start `sudo apt-get install -f` after that and give me a report.

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Comment: Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.   how to remove this

Comment: should i install sqldeveloper through rpm method by using  alien.

Comment: yes output is same

Comment: not really =) compare this `Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5), libc6-i386 (>= 2.1.3)`

Comment: yes output is different. again same problem occurs

Comment: when i write sqldeveloper in terminal then it open oracle sql developer start page, so now where i write jdk installation path

Comment: If so, then you have nothing else to do. Enjoy.

Comment: thanks a lot.          But it is not showing in dash with image

Answer (score 0):

This is self explanatory. Try to install *libc6-amd64* before installing  *sqldeveloper* and you'll have no problem.

If you have Internet connection try:

```
  sudo apt-get install libc6-amd64
```

If you don't, download it manually from http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and install it using dpkg just like the previous package.

Comment: how can i install this

Comment: @Ankit_Chaudhary see the edited answer

Comment: sudo apt-get install libc6-amd64   
    Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   libc6-amd64:i386 is already the newest version.
   libc6-amd64:i386 set to manually installed.
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Comment: sir this command gives this output

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your package being NEWER than what the software supports.  You must uninstall, and reinstall with the older version.

Also:
Try installing, and if it fails run "sudo apt-get -f install" to see if you can fix any missing dependencies.