# How to install odbcinst and odbcinst1debian2 via dpkg -i, when they depend on each other?

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit.  Host is offline, and of necessity must stay that way.

I need to install odbc to talk with a remote database from a C++ application running on the system.

I have downloaded all packages required by "libmyodbc", and transferred them to the system:

```
mysql-common_5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb   '
libmysqlclient18_5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb
libodbc1_2.2.14p2-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb
odbcinst1debian2_2.2.14p2-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb
odbcinst_2.2.14p2-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb
libmyodbc_5.1.10-1_amd64.deb'
```

I am installing using dpkg -i, but get a conflict when trying to install obcinst*.deb and odbcinst1debian2*.deb:

```
Selecting previously unselected package odbcinst.
(Reading database ... 203584 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking odbcinst (from odbcinst_2.2.14p2-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of odbcinst:
odbcinst depends on odbcinst1debian2 (>= 2.2.14p2); however:
Package odbcinst1debian2 is not configured yet.
```

So *odbcinst* can't install because odbcinst1debian2 is not installed.  So I try to install odbcinst1debian2, and get:

```
Selecting previously unselected package odbcinst1debian2.
(Reading database ... 203563 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking odbcinst1debian2 (from odbcinst1debian2_2.2.14p2-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of odbcinst1debian2:
odbcinst1debian2 depends on odbcinst; however:
Package odbcinst is not installed.
```

So *odbcinst1debian2* can't install because odbcinst is not installed... I checked out the ubuntu site, and it shows that these libs depend on each other...  http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/odbcinst

Also, I found this discussion from Steve Langasek (creator of the odbc packaged) on this circular dependency, from 2009:   https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=545861

Steve states that "dpkg knows what to do with them"... but it doesn't seem to be able to resolve this issue.

Does anyone know how to install packages via 'dpkg' that depend on each other?

Is there a better way to do this (i.e. should I be using unixodbc instead)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install both deb packages at the same time.

Go into the download folder of `odbcinst1debian2_2.2.14p2-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb`
and `odbcinst_2.2.14p2-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb` and install via

```
sudo dpkg -i odbcinst*
```

or via

```
sudo dpkg -i odbcinst1debian2_2.2.14p2-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb odbcinst_2.2.14p2-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Or change the dependencies in one of deb files as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/675647/367165).

Comment: Perfect.  I was just starting to think "maybe there's a way to do them together...".   This worked!

Comment: I needed to use --force-overwrite for it to work: 
"sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite odbcinst*"